# How to keep the windows form always responsive during an API call

Tags: c#, wcf

I have developed an Windows applications using C#. In this application i have downloaded a csv file and processed the records one by one.
But when I try to call the API during form_load event the form never show until the file is download.
This make the application look like irresponsible and form appears after processing the records.
Can anyone point me out a better viable solution?
As per the suggestion it can be put on thread.

Let me elaborate the whole picture

[image]

Comment: This question has been asked more times than can be counted and the answer is always the same - put the slow-running code into a thread.

Comment: you have to perform slow running operations asynchronously. Check out this article for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx

Comment: @J... Umm...Welcome to the 21st century. We don't use Threads anymore. We don't use leeches in medicine either.

Comment: @Aron Whatever compiler magic you want to use, son, I assure you that asynchronous code ends up running in a separate thread.  Now get off my lawn!

Comment: @J... http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html Assuming Asynchronous interupt/callback style I/O.

Comment: @Aron Pure device I/O is completely different.  That article does not mean what you think it means.  In this case "downloading" and "processing" are two entirely different beasts.  Downloading can be done with raw, "threadless" (in the talk of that article) async.  Processing cannot.  Critically, we have to distinguish between *waiting* for something while doing nothing and *doing two somethings* at once.

Comment: @J... Opening up a socket sending a request, yes, that requires a thread. With TAP that is likely the UI thread. However the latency in the response requires no thread to "wait" for the response. Yes I agree that at the TCP/IP level there is a large amount of CPU work going on (assuming no TOE), but still at that level there is no .net thread. Now I won't pretend to know how the TCP/IP drivers in Windows are setup, but it is still possible to run that entirely through device I/O.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do the operation in a separate thread so the main UI thread is not starved from messaging UI events. Other way is to make asynchronous call to the WCF service call.